# Loop task through all input files python

Tags: python

I am trying to count all the As and Bs and Cs in all the .txt files I supply and make a .csv file that lists the counts one by one of all those letters.

The code here does all I want but only with the last file I supply instead of all of them.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import glob
import csv

#This will print out all files loaded in  the same directory and print them out
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt*'):
    print(filename)

#A B and C
substringA = "A"
Head1 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringA))
substringB = "B"
Head2 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringB))
substringC = "C"
Head3 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringC))
header = ("File", "A Counts" ,"B Counts" ,"C Counts")
analyzed = (filename, Head1, Head2, Head3)

#This will write a file named Analyzed.csv
with open('Analyzed.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    writer.writerow(header)
    writer.writerow(analyzed)
```

Comment: Is the code which is counting `A` `B` and `C` in the for loop or outside of it?

Comment: just move your counting code 4 spaces to the right for it to be inside `for` loop :)

Comment: I think that is exactly my issue. I don't know how I can loop my code that is counting through all files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another small change you need to make: you need to open as append, not write, as well as indent. Note that when you open as append, you won't overwrite anything that was there before, so I added the portion at the top to delete anything already in the csv.

```
import glob
import csv


#This will delete anything in Analzyed.csv if it exists and replace it with the header
with open('Analyzed.csv','w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    header = ("File", "A Counts" ,"B Counts" ,"C Counts")
    writer.writerow(header)

for filename in glob.glob('*.txt*'):
    print(filename)

    #A B and C
    substringA = "A"
    Head1 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringA))
    substringB = "B"
    Head2 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringB))
    substringC = "C"
    Head3 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringC))
    header = ("File", "A Counts" ,"B Counts" ,"C Counts")
    analyzed = (filename, Head1, Head2, Head3)

    #This will write a file named Analyzed.csv
    with open('Analyzed.csv', 'a', newline='') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(analyzed)
```

Above is my solution keeping as much of your code untouched as possible. Ideally, though, you would only open the file once, at the beginning of the file. This is how you would do that:

```
import glob
import csv


with open('Analyzed.csv','w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    header = ("File", "A Counts" ,"B Counts" ,"C Counts")
    writer.writerow(header)

    for filename in glob.glob('*.txt*'):
        print(filename)

        #A B and C
        substringA = "A"
        Head1 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringA))
        substringB = "B"
        Head2 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringB))
        substringC = "C"
        Head3 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringC))
        analyzed = (filename, Head1, Head2, Head3)

        writer.writerow(analyzed)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. That works well. How to I avoid that it writes the head of the table multiple times. writer.writerow(header) do this just the very first time.

Comment: Whoops, I didn't notice that part, I'll add a fix

Answer (score 2):

Indentation was missing and open `Analyzed.csv` in append mode `a`:

```
import glob
import csv

#This will print out all files loaded in  the same directory and print them out
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt*'):
    print(filename)

    #A B and C
    substringA = "A"
    Head1 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringA))
    substringB = "B"
    Head2 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringB))
    substringC = "C"
    Head3 = (open(filename, 'r').read().count(substringC))
    header = ("File", "A Counts" ,"B Counts" ,"C Counts")
    analyzed = (filename, Head1, Head2, Head3)

    #This will write a file named Analyzed.csv
    with open('Analyzed.csv', 'a') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerow(analyzed)
```

EDIT: removed unsupported `newline=""` parameter

Comment: Will overwrite Analyzed.txt

Comment: You must open the output file before the for or open it in append mode (but it will not erase previous run data).

Comment: I changed it to opening in append mode `a`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
for filename in glob.glob('*.txt*'):
     data = chain.from_iterable([list(i.strip("\n")) for i in open(filename)])

     the_count = Counter(data)
     with open('Analyzed.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
         writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
         writer.writerow(filename)
         writer.writerow("A count: {}".format(the_count["A"]))
         writer.writerow("B count: {}".format(the_count["B"]))
         writer.writerow("C count: {}".format(the_count["C"]))
```